# How to create a delta table with invalid characters in column headers

Tags: databricks, delta-lake

Looking for a work around to create delta table with invalid character (). Below is the example

```sql
CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `Error_Description` STRING,
  `Age(months)` STRING,
  `%Role` STRING)
 USING Delta
```

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Attribute name "Age(months)" 
contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.
```

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/462 I suggest getting into the habit of never creating identifiers with non alphanumeric characters. You can always alias them.